# Sync local database with server on phonegap

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sqlite, cordova

Im creating a phonegap app that sync the data i add to the app with the server.

[Im using this as an example](https://github.com/abeauseigle/webSqlApp)

This app works like this, i scan a code (the database search if this code exist and finally, write a log on other table), check if the code exist to validate and write a log with good or bad response. I can send values to the server but the local database dont sync the server db, im working on this since one week ago and im very frustrated.

To avoid to write to much code, i show you the files where is all the queries and sync process [(index.html and setContact.php)](https://mega.nz/#!E1skkb5C!06BGxTl54PDLYt7VvILeX7YYr1BBW-XtMEtXIZ30OL4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to be sure your local and server database have the same fields, this helps to avoid many errors. This causes that you can send the values but not get the update back to the local app.

I did my app using the webSqlApp as an example, it works very good to do phonegap app with local<>server sync.